# What's the difference between 'Reflection' vs 'Variable variables' in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework

it seems that these 2 features has something in common, say, invoke a method just using its name in string. what's the difference? is there anything reflection can do but Variable variables can't?

even more, what's the difference between these 2 features' implementations in the PHP execution engine(VM)

Comment: Reflection can do a _lot_ more than variable variables. http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Comment: They have very little to do with each other. Variable variables are just a slightly eccentric feature. Reflection is used to reverse engineer classes and other stuff; a much more useful and complicated feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't have anything to do with each other.

Variable variables let you utilize a variable containing a string to access the contents of a different variable.  They are confusing and rarely used in my experience.

```
<?php
$first = 'Bob';
$last = 'Smith';

$t = 'first';
echo $t;
echo $$t;

$t = 'last';
echo $t;
echo $$t;
```

Reflection is a general term used to describe facilities in a language or library that let you discover the structure of a class.  This is often useful to framework or component developers who are trying to implement design patterns that work with user supplied classes or have highly generic functionality.  They're also very helpful if you are generating php code, or providing a tool that documents existing code.

As you can see from the api documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php this provides you ways to determine at runtime the properties and methods of a class.

Comment: $object->$t is that the same as variable variables?

Comment: Not really - it is basically the same as `$array[$t]`, but with objects.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini: The snippet provided shows variable variables.  It's the "$$t".   What you've noticed is that you can set a variable to be the name of a method or an attribute and access it.  $object->$t, $object->$t().  Along those lines, method_exists, call_user_func and call_user_func_array are often utilized in this area for "reflection" driven libraries.